# calling objects of functions in constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys i know it is dummy question but i tried a lot and never reached .. here is my code in jsp

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDepartment();" id="dep">Departments</button>
function deleteDep(id){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/Spring3HibernateApp1/deleteDep',
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                "id" : id,
            },
            dataType : "json"
        });
    }

    function loadDepartment(){
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : '/Spring3HibernateApp1/indexDep',
                type : 'GET',
                error : function(that, e) {
                    alert(e);
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    var newData = data.MyListDep;
                    gridDep = new GridLibraryDep({data: newData, deletefunction: deleteDep(id)});
                    gridDep.display();

                }
            });
        });
        }
```

and in JS

```js
function GridLibraryDep(data, deletefunction) {
 this.data = data.data;
 this.deletefunction = deletefunction.deletefunction(id);
  }

GridLibraryDep.prototype = {
  deleteRow : function() {
  $("input:checkbox:checked").each(bindContext(function(index, item) {
   var str = $(item).attr("id");
   str = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);
   var id = this.data[str][this.columns[1]];

   this.deletefunction(id);
   
   this.data.splice(str, 1);
   this.deleteTable();
   this.display();
  }, this));

 }}
```

i want to access the deletefunction in jsp and use it in js .. but it gives em id not defined in jsp ..  any suggestions ??

Comment: Look at which parameters you pass and which are declared...

Comment: Then you have to pass the function, not the result of a function call...

Comment: and thats what i am doing .. i am using deleteDep(id)

Comment: Try adding `dataType:'json';` to `loadDepartment` ajax call and remove `$.ready` from this function too;

Comment: `typeof deleteDep` vs `typeof deleteDep(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it overcomplicated and wrong.

Correct this line:

```
gridDep = new GridLibraryDep({data: newData, deletefunction: deleteDep(id)});
```

to:

```
gridDep = new GridLibraryDep(newData, deleteDep);
```

And the constructor:

```
function GridLibraryDep(data, deletefunction) {
  this.data = data.data;
  this.deletefunction = deletefunction.deletefunction(id);
}
```

to:

```
function GridLibraryDep(data, deletefunction) {
  this.data = data;
  this.deletefunction = deletefunction;
}
```

Now the declared and passed parameters match and the function is passed instead of function call result.

Comment: what if i want to call it like this gridDep = new GridLibraryDep({data: newData, deletefunction: deleteDep(id)}); ??

Comment: @yomnaesam then you have to modify the constructor to `function GridLibraryDep(obj) {
  this.data = obj.data;
  this.deletefunction = obj.deletefunction;
}` and remove `(id)` so  `gridDep = new GridLibraryDep({data: newData, deletefunction: deleteDep})`